# CCNet Security Exception

Tags: security, exception, cruisecontrol.net

I have just implemented CCNet security and I am able to login via the WebDashboard.

The problem is, when I try to force a build I get the following exception.

**Exception Message**

*Request processing has failed on the remote server: Permission to execute 'ViewProject' has been denied.*

```
Exception Full Details
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.CommunicationsException: Request processing has failed on the remote server:
Permission to execute 'ViewProject' has been denied.
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.CruiseServerClient.ValidateResponse(Response response)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.CruiseServerClient.ListBuildParameters(String projectName)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.ServerConnection.ServerAggregatingCruiseManagerWrapper.ListBuildParameters(IProjectSpecifier projectSpecifier, String sessionToken)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.Dashboard.ProjectParametersAction.Execute(ICruiseRequest cruiseRequest)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.Cruise.CruiseActionProxyAction.Execute(IRequest request)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.WebDashboard.MVC.Cruise.ExceptionCatchingActionProxy.Execute(IRequest request)
```

My security config looks like this:

**Server Security**

```
<internalSecurity>  
<cache type="inMemoryCache" duration="10" mode="sliding"/> 

<audit>
<xmlFileAudit location="C:\CCNet\CCNet_Audit.xml"/>
</audit>
<auditReader type="xmlFileAuditReader" location="C:\CCNet\CCNet_Audit.xml"/>

<users>
<ldapUser name="*" domain="company_domain" />
</users>

<permissions>
<rolePermission name="admin" forceBuild="Allow" sendMessage="Allow" startProject="Allow" changeProject="Allow" viewSecurity="Allow" modifySecurity="Allow" viewProject="Allow" viewConfiguration="Allow" defaultRight="Inherit">
<users>
<userName name="PROD_ADMINS" /> <!--AD User Group -->
</users>
</rolePermission>
</permissions>
</internalSecurity>
```

**Project Security**

```
<security type="defaultProjectSecurity">
<permissions>
<rolePermission name="admin" ref="admin"/>
</permissions>
</security>
```

The audit logs capture my name correctly from AD, so the authentication seems to be working fine.

Not sure what is going wrong..I have tried everything mentioned in the docs but it does not work!
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Ujjwal

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to set the defaultRight
defaultRight="Deny"
or 
defaultRight="Allow"

see here for the docs 
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Role_Permission

look at the full example at the wiki
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Scenario_1_Small_In-house_Development_Team
 this gives more information :-)

Comment: I am using the defaultRight = "Inherit", which is one of the valid options. I have tried with "Allow & "Deny" as well, and have the same issue.Not sure why it does not identify me belonging to the APP_ADMINS group...

Answer (score 0):

OK...it finally worked!

Here's how:

The config was correct except for CCNet **does not support AD groups** yet!
Once I replaced `<userName name="PROD_ADMINS" />` with actual user id identified by AD, it worked like a charm! :)

See the **EDIT 2** comment on [this](http://notonlysoftware.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/cruisecontrolnet-setting-ldap-without.html) blog for more details.

Regards
Ujjwal